# How to add image in drop-down list options using html and css only?

Tags: html, css

- I want to `add an image` to each option of the `drop-down list` using HTML and CSS only.

[SRC](http://jsfiddle.net/n4xfcvsw/119/)

Comment: A.k.a. how do I do the most basic research, by simply typing my question title into Google verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
  <option style="background-image:url(image1.jpg);">option1</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: Not working @Saranya Rajendran